# WooCommerce - Adding Custom Fields To Invoice

Tags: custom-field, woocommerce-offtopic, advanced-custom-fields

I am using the plugin listed below and I am trying to add in custom fields I have created on each order, such as shop notes, assigned staff member etc - but I can't work out how to add each custom field to the print order.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-delivery-notes/

Can anyone tell me the code to use and where I can find the custom field ID.

Hope someone knows how to do this :)